# Beyondcode Laravel Websockets : failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: laravel, websocket, echo, pusher

Local websockets is running like a charm but on production I keep getting the error in the title.

Some background information I'm using the websocket package: beyondcode/laravel-websockets. I'm running 'php artisan websockets:serve --port=6004' with supervisor. I also made sure port 6004 is open.

In production I tried the settings with and without SSL both gave the error in the title.

#### Settings with SSL:

**My echo settings:**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6004,
    wssPort: 6004,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

**My pusher settings:**

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6004,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

**My websockets settings:**

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],

    'ssl' => [
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => base_path().'/ssl/server.crt',

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => base_path().'/ssl/server.pem',

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => null,
        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
```

#### Settings without SSL:

**My echo settings:**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6004,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

**My pusher settings:**

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6004,
                'scheme' => 'http',
            ],
        ],
```

**My websockets settings:**

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],

    'ssl' => [
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => null,

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => null,

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => null,

    ],
```

Answer (score 14):

In my case after downgrading pusher from 6 something to

```
"pusher-js": "^4.3.1"
```

it started to work. Javascript I love you!

Comment: where should I put this or how should I downgrade?I checkeed composer.json but did not find anything

Comment: pusher-js it's a npm package. You have it in package.json

Answer (score 13):

so after a few days of fighting with ssl, I have to share with my knowledge in this topic..
After installation according to docs, websockets was worked with http, but not after using ssl(443).
I think I had a problem with the correct settings and path to .pem (Let's Encrypt)(I tried everything, this work for me). I use normal settings for Apatche2 mydomain.conf with port*:443, on VPS server.

websockets.php:

```
  'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
            'encrypted' => true,
        ],
    ],
  'ssl' => [ 
        'local_cert' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/server1.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem',
        'local_pk' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/server1.mydomain.com/privkey.pem', 
        'passphrase' => null,
        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
```

broadcasting.php:

```
      'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => 'server1.mydomain.com',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

bootstrap.js:

```
  window.Echo = new Echo({
        auth:{ headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token } },
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
        cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
        wsHost: window.location.hostname,
        wsPort: 6001,
        wssPort: 6001,
        disableStats: false, 
        enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
 });
```

I hope this will be helpful.
thank you, good luck and see you soon:)

Comment: You are a lifesaver, this finally worked for me.

For clarity for future readers - in your apache conf file, you do not need to use proxy pass or rewriteengine to ws:// or wss:// (if the socketserver is being served by that virtual host) - hence " I use normal settings for Apatche2 mydomain.conf with port*:443"

For a proof of concept, I copied the certificate files to the /config directory and chowned them to www-data. As for the final solution, you can copy the files and recopy everytime you renew the certificate or give permissions to the files (symlinking doesn't seem to work).

Comment: man, you saved my life . This answer is what I was looking for :) . Thanks youuuu.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this problem and published a more detailed question where I showed you the settings for **firewall**, **laravel**, **nuxt**, **nginx** and **websockets**. A few days later, a solution was found: [Laravel + Nuxt + Nginx: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512025/2590810)

`For comparison, see also the question itself on the link above.`

## Project settings

### Firewall

**netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN**

```
root@dsde1032-21892:~# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1066/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7768/php
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1064/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1173/node
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1066/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1078/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1064/sshd
```

**lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN**

```
root@dsde1032-21892:~# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
sshd     1064     root    3u  IPv4  20044      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd     1064     root    4u  IPv6  20138      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
nginx    1066     root    6u  IPv4  20168      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx    1066     root    7u  IPv4  20169      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
mysqld   1078    mysql   31u  IPv4  20463      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
node     1173     root   18u  IPv4  20902      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
nginx    7402 www-data    6u  IPv4  20168      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx    7402 www-data    7u  IPv4  20169      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
php      7768     root    5u  IPv4 110549      0t0  TCP *:6001 (LISTEN)
```

**ufw status**

```
root@dsde1032-21892:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
6001                       ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
6001 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**ufw show listening**

```
root@dsde1032-21892:~# ufw show listening
tcp:
  22 * (sshd)
   [ 1] allow OpenSSH

  443 * (nginx)
   [ 2] allow 'Nginx Full'

  6001 * (php7.4)
   [ 3] allow 6001

  80 * (nginx)
   [ 2] allow 'Nginx Full'

tcp6:
  22 * (sshd)
   [ 4] allow OpenSSH
```

### Laravel

**vim /var/www/api/config/websockets.php**

```
...
    'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => false,
        ],
    ],
...
    'ssl' => [
        'local_cert' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/larastart.site/fullchain.pem',
        'local_pk' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/larastart.site/privkey.pem',
        'passphrase' => null,
        'verify_peer' => false
    ],
...
```

**vim /var/www/api/config/broadcasting.php**

```
...
    'connections' => [
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]

            ],
        ],
...
    ],
...
```

### Nuxt

**vim /var/www/client/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "port": "3000"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "export": "nuxt export",
    "serve": "nuxt serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.2",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/laravel-echo": "^1.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.0.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.13.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**vim /var/www/client/plugins/echo.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

export default (app) => {
    window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: process.env.BROADCAST_DRIVER,
        key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
        cluster: process.env.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,

        forceTLS: true,
        encrypted: false,
        wsHost: window.location.hostname,
        wsPort: 6001,
        wssPort: 6001,
        disableStats: true,
        enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
    });
}
```

### Nginx

**vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

**vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/larastart.site**

```
server {
        server_name     larastart.site;
        root            /var/www/api/public;

        add_header X-Frame-Options              "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection             "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options       "nosniff";

        # Priority file extensions
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        charset utf-8;

        # Check for the existence of files matching a provided url, forward to 404 if not found
        location /api {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # Serve static files directly
        location ~* ^/storage/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png|ico)$ {
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host               $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;

                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-VerifiedViaNginx yes;
                proxy_read_timeout                  300;
                proxy_connect_timeout               300;
        }

        location /app {
                proxy_pass             https://larastart.site:6001;
                proxy_read_timeout     60;
                proxy_connect_timeout  60;
                proxy_redirect         off;

                # Allow the use of websockets
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root concurs with nginx's one
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
               deny all;
        }

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/larastart.site/fullchain.pem;     # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/larastart.site/privkey.pem;       # managed by Certbot
        include             /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;                # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam         /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;                      # managed by Certbot
}

server {
        if ($host = larastart.site) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        server_name larastart.site;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also face that problem on my live server .  For me its not working because my port is not allow .`sudo ufw allow 6001` after put this command my live server start working .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjmDt.png)

Comment: This indeed was my issue, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

fixed the issue by adding ssl paths in websockets.php. I'm using a purchased ssl which I added in Plesk. In the cli the path to the certificates is from root: cd /usr/local/psa/var/certificates then I did 'ls' to check the certificate names. In my case I used the certificate with the private key and added as local_cert path and local_pk path in the config/websockets.php

#### Final settings:

**websockets.php**

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],

 'ssl' => [
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => env('ssl_certificate', null),

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => env('ssl_certificate_key', null),

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => null,
        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
```

**broadcasting.php**

```
 'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6004,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                 'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6004,
    wssPort: 6004,
    disableStats: true,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});
```

btw don't forget to run npm run dev when you change something in bootstrap.js
and I'm running it on port 6004 so if you run it on 6001 don't forget to change it my settings above

Answer (score 1):

Update 2023 with laravel 10,vue3, pusher-js 7.6

put this configs and you are good to go :

inside bootstrap.js :

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import pusherJs from 'pusher-js'
window.Pusher = pusherJs

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'local',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    cluster : 'mt1',
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

inside broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],
```

inside .env

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with these options in the "window.Echo" ?

```
 host:          window.location.hostname,
 httpHost:      window.location.hostname,
```

Comment: These days I saw many questions about Laravel Realtime topic.. planning to make a guide or video about that tomorrow with Laravel 6. If it will be ready, I'll put here the link, but I hope you'll find the solution before that..